# Connecting an auxiliary cable into three out of 9 serial pins

Tags: serial, cables

Please bear with me as I have no electrical engineering knowledge at all.

I have a device with the following connection (and connecting cable):

[image: connector with connection.]

which as far as I understand is called an SRT connector.

In every-day use it is connected with a 9-pin serial to another device, which then uses the same connection to transmit data (The small cable is the aux going into the serial, and then another cable leaves the serial, presumably using the other pins):
[image]

I would like to bypass the second device and connect the first device directly to my computer, through a 9-pin serial, and get the info it is transmitting. that is I would like to connect it to something like this:

[image]

which I'll then be able to connect to my computer.

Is such a thing possible? Suppose I somehow manage to find which of the Ring-Sleeve-Tip is for TX/RX/Ground, and I just build a cable that connects them accordingly, leaving the other 6 pins empty, will it work?

Comment: TRS to DB9 is not a standard serial connection, You will have to measure the connections with an ohmmeter and see if the TRS connections go straight through to the DB9 connector. If the pins go straight through, then it should be no problem to build a simpler cable.

Comment: Also, please edit your photos before posting.  I've cut them down to size, but some folks get really bent out of shape over sloppy posts and will down vote or ignore a question for just that reason.

Comment: @JRE Sorry for that, never tried uploading photos to stackexchange. On the preview given to me they seemed to be scaled down so I assumed it was automatic.

Comment: They get scaled to fit the display, but the DB9 was a picture of your table top with the DB9 somewhere on it.  The pictures are stored just as you uploaded them, and get scaled on the end users device.  On a smartphone, that can cost a lot of time or data.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. RS232 on stereo jack.*

It's most likely wired like this. Pin 5 and the sleeve (1) of the jack are always GND (ground) or COM (common). Pins 2 and 3 are transmit and receive. If it doesn't work one way then swap 2 and 3.

Comment: Will definitely try that and report back. Thanks!
One thing though, in the diagram isn't the sleeve connected to 2 and tip connected to 5? Which of them is the correct?

Comment: Oh, dear. I looked at it twice before posting. I can't mix cooking and SE. New image added.